# Github actions with pushing and building docker image to dockerhub , failed to compute cache key target folder not existing, spirng boot app

Tags: spring-boot, docker, github-actions, dockerhub

So i have dockerized spring boot application, i have docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:17
ADD target/KIII_Project_Final-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar KIII_Project_Final-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "KIII_Project_Final-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

And my github action is :

```
name: Build & Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build_and_push:
    name: Build & Push to DockerHub
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Docker Build and Push to DockerHub
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: markoblazhevski/kiii:latest
```

and i get this error :
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount183090869/target: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount183090869/target: no such file or directory

my github repository looks like this:
[IMAGE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aEXF.png)
I need help guys

I tried changing the action but it seems somehow the target folder cant be found , and i cant upload it and i dont know what to do, do i need to add something to my application or do i need to build it ?
I am new to this so please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be two solutions:

1. After docker login you can build and push by simple docker command

   ```
   - name: Docker Build and Push to DockerHub

     run: |

       docker build -t markoblazhevski/kiii:latest .

       docker push markoblazhevski/kiii:latest
   ```
2. Other way is if you want to use this action then you need to setup buildx first before the build and push step. You can follow the [documentation here](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action).

Comment: Thanks so much i used this code and it worked, i just needed to change the dockerfile and add jar file to github.